# Проверка чекбоксов через БД

Tags: php

Есть `n` чекбоксов, при клике на каждый идет запись в БД с `id` юзера и `id` чекбокса в отдельную таблицу. Как правильно проверять условия на кликнутый, либо не кликнутый чекбокс, чтобы после повторной загрузки страницы чекбоксы, которые были отмечены, оставались отмеченными? Пробовал как-то так, понимаю, что есть ошибка в самом цикле, но вот как исправить, увы, не знаю:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count(массив с чекбоксами); $i++){
   if (count(массив с чекбоксами) >0 ){
          $active = "";
       if (айди чекбокса[$i] != ""){
          $active = "active" // класс для включенного чекбокса
    }

}
$checkbox .= "<div class="check_ '.$m_active.'"></div>";
}
```

Вполне понятно, что если, допустим, есть 3 кнопки, и отжать вторую кнопку, то через такой цикл будут активными 1-ая и 2-ая кнопки.

Comment: зачем этот чекбокс  if (count(массив с чекбоксами) >0 ){

Comment: что бы проверить есть ли вообще чекбоксы

Comment: Вы внутрь цикла не попадете, если чекбоксов не будет. так что проверка на count внутри действительно не нужна. И не понятно, почему у вас некая переменная никак не привязанная ни к каким конкретным чекбоксам получает значение active. Она же станет active как только будет найден любой чекбокс.

Comment: испрвил, в 3й строке пустую строку принимает

Comment: вообще я как бы ожидал, что в самом цикле будет формирование этих самых чекбоксов. По данному коду вообще не понятно как и когда данная переменная попадает в чекбокс

Comment: в цикле и попадает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ressult = array()
foreach (массив с чекбоксами as $key => $val){
       $ressult[$key]['value'] = $val;
       if(isset($idCheckbox[$key]) != '') {
          $ressult[$key]['checked'] = 'checked';
       } else {
          $ressult[$key]['checked'] = '';
       }
}
```

получим результат в виде array который можно перебрать уже в шаблоне

```
<form>
<?php foreach($ressult as $key => $_res): ?>
<checkbox name="testing[<?php echo $key ?>]" value="<?php echo $_res['value']?>" 
      <?php echo $_res['checked'] ?> /> <?php echo $_res['value'] ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: не совсем ясно зачем 2 цикла и зачем foreach

Comment: вторым циклом я просто показал ка это можно реализовать в шаблоне если шаблоны есть

Comment: попробовал сделать как Вы подсказали, получается как и в 1 варианте - отметил 1 и 3 , перезагрузил, активные 1 и 2

Comment: т.к если удалять тот же 2 элемент, то `$ressult` будет выглядеть как `{1,3,null}` вместо `{1,null,3}`

Comment: немного подправил вывиде в масиве имени ключ который будет уникален, тогда можно проследить где и когда ошибка произошла